# How do I make a QVector of widgets?

Tags: qt, qt4, qwidget, qvector

How do I make a `QVector` (or some other container class) of a dynamic number of widgets, such as `QPushButton` or `QComboBox` in Qt 4?

I've used the following in my window class's constructor:

```
QVector<QComboBox*> foo; // Vector of pointers to QComboBox's
```

And now I want to fill it with some number of controls which can change dynamically:

```
for(int count = 0; count < getNumControls(); ++count) {
    foo[count] = new QComboBox();
}
```

I've searched for hours trying to find the answer to this. The Qt forums mention making a `QPtrList`, but that class no longer exists in Qt4.
I'd later try to get the text value from each using array-style indexing or the `.at()` function.

I would really appreciate an example of declaring, initializing, and populating any data structure of any `QWidgets` (`QComboBox`, `QPushButton`, etc.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here you go :)

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QList>
#include <QLabel>
...
QList< QLabel* > list;
...

list << new QLabel( parent, "label 1" );
..
..

foreach( QLabel* label, list )  {
label->text();
label->setText( "my text" );
}
```

If you are trying just to get a simple example to work, its important that your widgets have a parent (for context / clean up) purposes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wanted to insert combo-boxes from the .ui file into a list. I inserted this way: `QList<QComboBox *> listComboBox;` `listComboBox << (ui->comboBoxTitle);` and retrieved like this: `QComboBox *comboBox = listComboBox.at(i);` which is working all fine! : )

Comment: QVector is now preferred to QList ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38263633/6165833)).

Answer (score 0):

```
foo[count] = new QComboBox();
```

This won't affect the size of foo.  If there isn't already an item at index count, this will fail.
See [push_back](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qvector.html#push_back), or [operator<<](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qvector.html#operator-lt-lt), which add an item to the end of the list.

```
QVector<QComboBox*> foo;
// or QList<QComboBox*> foo;
for(int count = 0; count < getNumControls(); ++count) {
    foo.push_back(new QComboBox());
    // or foo << (new QComboBox());
}
```

Later, to retrieve the values:

```
foreach (QComboBox box, foo)
{
  // do something with box here
}
```