# QList vs QVector revisited

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlist, qvector

My question is basically when to choose `QVector` and when to choose `QList` as your Qt container. What I already know:

1. Qt docs: [QList class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#details)

> For most purposes, QList is the right class to use. Its index-based API is more convenient than QLinkedList's iterator-based API, and it is usually faster than QVector because of the way it stores its items in memory. It also expands to less code in your executable.

2. The same is written is this very popular Q&A: [QVector vs QList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602036/qvector-vs-qlist). It also favors QList.
3. But: on recent Qt World Summit 2015 KDAB presented "Why QList is harmful", this is basically here:

[QList considered harmful](https://marcmutz.wordpress.com/2010/07/29/sneak-preview-qlist-considered-harmful/)

[Don't use QList, use Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2015-July/022285.html)

As far as I understand the idea is that `QList` for almost all types is inefficient when allocating new elements in heap. Each time you are adding new element, it calls `new` (once per element) and this is inefficient compared to `QVector`.

This is why now I am trying to understand: is it `QVector` which we should choose as default container?

Comment: I don't believe there is such a thing as a "default container".

Comment: Well, by default container I mean container that can be used in the most situations. In the sense the Qt doc is saying about Qlist "For most purposes, QList is the right class to use"

Comment: This is only because Qt uses it as such. (And the two articles you point try to prove, it was not a good idea.) Anyways, if you are forced to use it because of some Qt interface - it is "the better choice", if not - well, It is up to you to decide, I see you have read more then enough information :)

Comment: My own current opinion is that you can choose QList or QVector depending on situation but Qt doc is misleading in this point. This is surprising for me because generally it is very good

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Qt advertises `QList` as the "jack of all trades", but the other half of that saying is "master of none". I'd say `QList` is a good candidate if you plan on appending to both ends of the list, and those are no larger than than a pointer, as `QList` reserves space before and after. That's about it, I mean as far as good reasons to use `QList` are concerned.

`QList` will automatically store "large" objects as pointer and allocate the objects on the heap, which may be considered a good thing if you are a baby, which doesn't know how to declare a `QVector<T*>` and use dynamic allocation. This is not necessarily a good thing, and in some cases it will only bloat the memory usage and add extra indirection. IMO it is always a good idea to be explicit about what you want, whether it is pointers or instances. Even if you do want heap allocation, it is always better to allocate it yourself and simply add the pointer to the list than construct the object once, then have have copy construct that on the heap.

Qt will return you a `QList` in a lot of places where it comes with overhead, for example when getting a `QObject`'s children or you search for children. In this case it doesn't make sense to use a container that allocates space before the first element, as it is a list of objects which are already there, not something you are likely to prepend to. I also don't much like the absence of a `resize()` method.

Imagine a situation where you have an object with size of 9 bytes and byte alignment on a 64 bit system. It is "far too much" for `QList` so instead it will use 8 byte pointer + CPU overhead for the slow heap allocation + memory overhead for the heap allocation. It will use twice the memory and with an extra indirection for access it will hardly offer performance advantages as advertised.

As of why `QVector` cannot suddenly become the "default" container - you don't change horses mid-race - it is a legacy thing, Qt being such an old framework, and even though a lot of stuff has been deprecated, making changes to widely used defaults is not always possible, not without breaking a lot of code, or producing undesired behavior. Good or bad, `QList` will likely continue being the default all the way throughout Qt 5, and likely in the next major release as well. The same reason Qt will continue using "dumb" pointers, for years after smart pointers have become a must and everybody is crying about how bad plain pointers are and how they should not be used ever.

That being said, nobody is forcing **you** to use `QList` in your design. There is no reason why `QVector` should not be **your** default container. I myself don't use `QList` anywhere, and in the Qt functions which return a `QList` I merely use as a temporary to move stuff into a `QVector`.

Furthermore, and this is only my personal opinion, but I do find a lot of design decisions in Qt that don't necessary make sense, be that performance or memory use efficiency or ease of use wise, and overall there are a a lot of frameworks and languages which like promoting their ways of doing things, not because it is the best way to do it, but because it is their way to do it.

Last but not least:

> For most purposes, QList is the right class to use.

It really boils down to how you understand this. IMO in this context, "the right" does not stand for "the best" or "the optimal", but for "good enough" as in "it will do, even if not the best". Especially if you know nothing about different container classes and how they work.

> For most purposes, QList will do.

---

**To sum things up:**

`QList` PROs

- you intend to prepend objects no larger than the size of a pointer, since it reserves *some* space in the front
- you intend to insert in the middle of the list objects (substantially) larger than a pointer (and I am being generous here, since you can easily use `QVector` with explicit pointers to achieve the same and cheaper - no extra copy), since when resizing the list, no objects will be moved, only pointers

`QList` CONs

- doesn't have a `resize()` method, `reserve()` is a subtle trap, since it will not increase the valid list size, even if index access works it falls in the UB category, also you will not be able to iterate that list
- does an extra copy and heap allocating when object is larger than a pointer, which might also be an issue if object identity matters
- uses extra indirection to access objects larger than a pointer
- has CPU time and memory usage overheads due to the last two, also less cache friendly
- comes with additional overhead when used as a "search" return value, since you are not likely to prepend or even append to that
- only makes sense if index access is a must, for optimal prepend and insert performance a linked list might be a better option.

The CON's marginally outweigh the PROs, meaning that while in "casual" use `QList` might be acceptable, you definitely don't want to use it in situations where CPU time and/or memory usage are a critical factor. All in all, `QList` is best suited for lazy and careless use, when you don't want to make the consideration of optimal storage container for the use case, which would typically be a `QVector<T>`, a `QVector<T*>` or a `QLinkedList` (and I exclude "STL" containers, since we are talking Qt here, Qt containers are just as portable, sometimes faster, and most certainly easier and cleaner to use, whereas `std` containers are needlessly verbose).

Comment: Naturally, I completely disagree with you. You make it sound like `QList` will not heap-allocate if the payload type is not larger than a pointer. That is only one of two conditions. The other is that the type is explictly marked as trivially relocatable by the class author. Most people don't do this. Most Qt developers (those that work on Qt as opposed to with Qt) don't do this. So `QList` can be considered to be an array-list (vector of pointers) for all intents and purposes. The problem is that an array-list is not a good data type for most use-cases.

Comment: `QList` will not be Qt 6. Not in the current form.

Comment: @MarcMutz-mmutz ah interesting. Do you have a list of things that will change in Qt6? What will happen with QList, will its API change in source-breaking ways? Or merely its inner workings? For me, the thing that keeps me using QList is that it's used a lot elsewhere, and it being slow should be fixed in Qt, not worked around in my code IMO. BTW, greetings from FFM ^^

Comment: @MarcMutz-mmutz - what you say is an important detail, but I find it quite ridiculous to "naturally completely disagree" with the answer because of something "wrong" that it did not state at all. Also, it doesn't seem that even the latest documentation about `QList` even remotely mentions "trivially realocable" types or anything on that subject, so feel free to fill in any omissions both in my answer and the Qt documentation instead of dramatizing ;)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: There will very likely be a `QList` for source-compat, but no Qt API will hopefully use it anymore. Apart from that, little is clear. I'd like to kill CoW, while others still hang on to it for dear life. If we actually get a clang dependency for `moc` and `qdoc`, then it should be easy to make a much better version of `qt3to4` and source compatibility would no longer be such an issue. In that case, I'd rename `QList`→`QArrayList` with no in-place optimisation and port the rest to `QVector`.

Comment: @ddriver: I disagree with the notion that "casual" use of `QList` might be acceptable. It's not.

Comment: @MarcMutz-mmutz - can you make a distinction between "your personal opinion" and "in practice"? What my answer stresses is that QList "sucks" and is rarely the optimal choice. Even if not the best solution, QList will work in most, if not all cases, so it is safe to say that it "might be acceptable". Acceptable doesn't mean perfect or optimal, it means an acceptable level of compromise. And as the answer you "completely disagree"  with goes to say - if performance and efficiency is a priority, QList is definitely NOT the right choice. But it will do if you don't care, i.e. the "casual use".

Comment: @MarcMutz-mmutz How do these Qt src changes apply to built-in Qt classes like `QStringList` that utilize `QList`? Will they be deprecated, too, or quietly ported to use `QVector` instead?

Comment: @ddriver: This has nothing to do with "personal opinion". `QList` changes layout depending on very subtle differences in environment (like the machine's word size), and with it change the container guarantees. So, `QList<double>` has stable references to the elements on 32-bit systems. Not so on 64-bit systems. Such a container is simply unacceptable, and should be avoided at all cost. If you use `QList` today, in new code, I'm sorry, but you deserve it.

Comment: @Phlucious: I don't know. The use of the -List suffix for containers is very unfortunate. It might happen that `QStringList` will, indeed, be a vector. I doubt it will be deprecated anytime soon. But I'm pretty sure it will not be `QList<QString>` anymore in Qt 6.

Comment: @MarcMutz-mmutz - I don't think that "casual usage" even stacks with "container guarantees" once again you are stressing things which go without saying. If you want guarantees, you don't go casually about it. I personally never chose to use QList, I only use it when there is no other way - i.e. when the Qt APIs return it. Also, as my answer conclusion notes, the negative aspects of QList outweigh the positive, and that QList is "lazy and careless use". So... you are kind of dramatizing.

Answer (score 20):

In Qt 5.7, the documentation was changed concerning the topic discussed here. In [QVector](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html) it is now stated:

> `QVector` should be your default first choice. `QVector<T>` will usually give better performance than `QList<T>`, because `QVector<T>` always stores its items sequentially in memory, where `QList<T>` will allocate its items on the heap unless `sizeof(T)` <= `sizeof(void*)` and `T` has been declared to be either a `Q_MOVABLE_TYPE` or a `Q_PRIMITIVE_TYPE` using `Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO`.

They refer to this [article by Marc Mutz](https://marcmutz.wordpress.com/effective-qt/containers/#containers-qlist).

So the official point of view has changed.

Comment: Too bad they did not update clearly the [container classes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html) page. It first says _if you need a resizable array of QStrings, use QVector<QString>_ and just after _For most applications, QList is the best type to use_

Comment: By the end of 2017 in Qt 5.10 documentation all this mess unfortunately still exists :(

Answer (score 5):

`QList` is an array of `void*`.

In its normal operation, it `new`s the elements on the heap and stores a pointer to them in the `void*` array. Like a linked list, that means that references (but, unlike linked lists, not iterators!) to elements contained in the list remain valid under all container modifications until the element is removed from the container again. Thus the name "list". This datastructure is called an array-list and is used in a lot of programming languages where every object is of reference type (say, Java). It is a very cache-unfriendly data structure, like all node-based containers.

But the resizing of the array-list can be factored into a type-independent helper class (`QListData`), which is supposed to save some executable code size. In my experiments, it's next to impossible to predict which of `QList`, `QVector` or `std::vector` produces the least executable code.

This would have been a good data type for the many Qt reference-like types such as `QString`, `QByteArray`, etc., which consist of nothing more than a pimpl pointer. For these types, `QList` gained an important optimisation: when the type is not larger than a pointer (and please note that this definition depends on the platform's pointer size - 32 or 64bits), instead of heap-allocating objects, the objects are stored in the `void*` slots directly.

This is only possible, though, if the type is *trivially relocatable*. That means it can be relocated in memory using `memcpy`. Relocation here means I take an object, `memcpy` it to another address and - crucially - *not* run the destructor of the old object.

And this is where things started to go wrong. Because unlike in Java, in C++ a reference to an object is its *address*. And while in the original `QList`, references were stable until the object was removed from the collection again, by putting them into the `void*` array this property no longer holds. This is no longer a "list" for all intents and purposes.

Things continued to go wrong, though, because they allowed types that are strictly smaller than a `void*` to be placed in a `QList`, too. But the memory management code expects elements of pointer size, so `QList` adds padding(!). That means that a `QList<bool>` on 64bit platforms looks like this:

```
[ | | | | | | | [ | | | | | | | [ ...
[b|   padding   [b|   padding   [b...
```

Instead of fitting 64 bools into a cache line, like `QVector` does, `QList` only manages *8*.

Things went wrong out of any proportion when the docs started calling `QList` a good default container. It's not. The [original STL states](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html):

> `Vector` is the simplest of the STL container classes, and in many cases the most efficient.

Scott Meyer's *Effective STL* has several items that start with "Prefer `std::vector` over...".

What is true in general C++ is not suddenly wrong just because you're using Qt.

Qt 6 will fix that particular design mistake. In the meantime, use `QVector` or `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3):

> If the size of the QList's element type is greater than the pointer's
>   size QList performs better than QVector because it doesn't store the
>   objects sequentially but stores sequentially pointers to heap copies.

I'd tend to say the opposite. It'll be much worse off, when going through the items.
If it stores it as pointers on the heap won't QList be much worse off than QVector? The reason that sequential storage(QVector all the time) is so good is, that is is cache friendly, once you store pointers,you lose the data locality, start getting cache misses and it's horrible for performance.

The "default" container IMHO should be a QVector (or std::vector), if you're worried about lots of reallocation, then preallocate a reasonable amount, pay the once off cost and you'll benefit in the long run.

Use the *Vector by default, if you get performance problems, profile and change as necessary.

Comment: I'd agree too. If I have an 8 byte struct and I add 100 of them to a QVector I use up 800bytes, give or take housekeeping. If I add the same 8 byte struct one 100 times to a QList, I have (assuming 32-bits) 400 bytes allocated for pointers and additional 100 8 byte heap allocs plus a lot more housekeeping. It's horribly inefficient. QList has its place but it's an attractive nuisance, particularly for embedding where heap fragmentation is a real problem.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that this has completely changed in Qt6:
https://www.qt.io/blog/qlist-changes-in-qt-6

QVector and QList are unified and the model of QVector is used as the underlying implementation. This means that Qt 5 QList's extra level of indirection for generic types is now gone and elements are always directly stored in the allocated memory. QList is the real class, with implementation, while QVector is just an alias to QList. QList in Qt 6 supports optimised prepend. It may now shrink on elements removal without usage of reserve. And the size limit of 2GB is removed.

Answer (score 0):

QList is the best possible container to use generally as the documentation states. If the size of the elements' type is <= of the pointer's size = machine & OS bitness = 4 or 8 bytes then the objects are stored the same way as QVector does - sequentially in memory. If the size of the QList's element type is greater than the pointer's size QList performs better than QVector because it doesn't store the objects sequentially but stores sequentially pointers to heap copies.
In the 32-bit case the picture is as follows:

```
sizeof( T ) <= sizeof( void* )
=====
QList< T > = [1][1][1][1][1]
                   or
             [2][2][2][2][2]
                   or
             [3][3][3][3][3]
                   or
             [4][4][4][4][4] = new T[];

sizeof( T ) > sizeof( void* )
=====
QList< T > = [4][4][4][4][4] = new T*[]; // 4 = pointer's size
              |   |  ...  |
           new T new T   new T
```

In case you want your objects to be laid out sequentially in memory no matter the size of their elements, as it is usually the case with OpenGL programming, then you should use QVector.

Here is a [detailed description](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#details) of the QList's internals.

Comment: All wrong. `QList` is only layout-compatible with `QVector` and thus a C array when `sizeof T == sizeof void*`. And if the type is explicitly marked `Q_MOVABLE_TYPE`. Yes, that differs between 32 and 64-bit platforms. If `sizeof T < sizeof void*`, `QList` pads. A `QList<bool>` thus uses 8x the memory of a `QVector<bool>` and 64x the memory of a `std::vector<bool>`, though the `bool` specialisation of `std::vector` is widely considered to have been a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine, that we have DataType class.

QVector - array of objects, such as:

```
// QVector<DataType> internal structure
DataType* pArray = new DataType[100];
```

QList - array of pointers to objects, such as:

```
// QList<DataType> internal structure
DataType** pPointersArray = new DataType*[100];
```

Therefore, direct access by index will be faster for QVector:

```
{
// ...
cout << pArray[index]; //fast
cout << *pPointersArray[index]; //slow, need additional operation for dereferencing
// ...
}
```

But swaping will be faster for QList, if sizeof(DataType) > sizeof(DataType*):

```
{
// QVector swaping
DataType copy = pArray[index];
pArray[index] = pArray[index + 1];
pArray[index + 1] = copy; // copy object

// QList swaping
DataType* pCopy = pPointersArray [index];
pPointersArray[index] = pPointersArray [index + 1];
pPointersArray[index + 1] = pCopy; // copy pointer
// ...
}
```

So, if you need direct access without swaping operations between elements (such as sorting, for example), or sizeof(DataType) <= sizeof(DataType*), your better way is use QVector. In other case use QList.

Comment: This is not correct: Depending on the contents type, QList is implemented in the background just like a QVector, therefore a downvote.

Comment: @dhaumann can you provide link to documentation or source code?

Comment: Yes, see [QList source code](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qlist.h.html#114) (note the struct MemoryLayout...,) or [here](https://swanson.kdab.com/owncloud/index.php/s/Mj9n7KxLVj2HPvz).

Comment: Better yet, see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sl4yvAWbcmE&t=1530).

Comment: @dhaumann I saw all of this, but still not understand how QList can have structure such as qvector.

Comment: Ok, I guess I was too aggressive here: You are correct with what you say with respect to swapping elements. But then again, if one has a pointer in a QList, one should go for a QVector<T*> or better yet std::vector<T*> right away. There, you have the quick swapping as well without the different interpretations QList has, depending on its contents size and Q_MOVABLE_TYPE flag.

Comment: @dhaumann Q_MOVABLE_TYPE has sense for all types of Qt containers and mean is container can copy element via memcpy function or need to call copy consturctor, that always slower. I don't see any dependencies in QList from Q_MOVABLE_TYPE. I see in source code dependence from sizeof(void*) in memory layouting, but still not understand is it really such as QVector structure QList have if sizeof(DataType) == sizeof(void*)

Answer (score 0):

QList behaves differently depending on what's inside (see [source code](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qlist.h.html#114) `struct MemoryLayout`):

- if `sizeof T == sizeof void*` and `T` is defined `Q_MOVABLE_TYPE`, then `QList<T>` behaves exactly like `QVector`, that is, the data is stored contiguously in memory.
- if `sizeof T < sizeof void*` and `T` is defined `Q_MOVABLE_TYPE`, then `QList<T>` pads each entry to `sizeof void*`, and loses layout-compatibility with QVector.
- in all other cases, `QList<T>` is a linked list and therefore slow to some degree.

This behavior is what makes `QList<T>` pretty much always a bad choice, because depending on nifty details, `QList<T>` is either really a list, or a vector. That's bad API design and prone to errors. (For instance, you will run into bugs if you have a library with a public interface that uses a `QList<MyType>` internally and in its public interface. `sizeof MyType is < sizeof void*`, but say you forgot to declare MyType as `Q_MOVABLE_TYPE`. Later, you want to add `Q_MOVABLE_TYPE`. This is binary incompatible, meaning that you now have to recompile all code that uses your library, as the memory layout of `QList<MyType>` changed in the public API. If you are not careful, you will miss this and introduce a bug. This illustrates quite nicely why QList is a bad choice here.)

That said, QList is still not entirely bad: It will probably do what you want most of the cases, but maybe it will do the job behind the scenes differently to what you might expect.

Rule of thumb is:

- Instead of QList, use `QVector<T>` or `QVector<T*>`, since it explicitly says what you want. You can combine that with `std::unique_ptr`.
- In C++11 and onwards, it is even considered best to just use `std::vector`, since it will behave correctly in a [range-based for loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sl4yvAWbcmE&t=1870). (QVector and QList may detach and therefore perform a deep-copy).

You can find all these details and more in a [presentation from Marc Mutz](https://swanson.kdab.com/owncloud/index.php/s/Mj9n7KxLVj2HPvz) and in the video by [Olivier Goffart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sl4yvAWbcmE&t=1530).

Comment: The first case needs to say =, not ≤. Then add another case:   - if `sizeof T < sizeof void*` and `T` is defined `Q_MOVABLE_TYPE`, then `QList<T>` pads each entry to `sizeof void*`, and loses layout-compatibility with `QVector`. Then the description is correct.