# Reading a QList<QPoint> in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have the following class definition:

```
class PlaneGridQML : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ........
    Q_INVOKABLE QList<QPoint> getPlanesPoints() {
        return m_PlaneGrid.getPlanesPoints();
    ......
}
```

In main I am making it available to the QML engine

```
PlaneGridQML pgq(10, 10, 3, false);
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("PlaneGrid",&pgq);
```

Then inside a QML Component I would like to do the following:

```
Connections {
    target: PlaneGrid
    onPlanesPointsChanged: {
        var pointsArray = PlaneGrid.getPlanesPoints()
        console.log(pointsArray[0].x)
    }
}
```

I am getting an error "Unknown method return type: QList" and obviously I cannot read pointsArray and display its first member. According to the Qt documentation QPoint can be directly transferred as a JS type. On the other hand `QPoint` does not derive from `QObject`.

Can anyone explain how can I list the elements of the array ( the `QPoints` ) in the JS function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a `QPoint` will be auto converted to QML, and even a `QList` of certain objects will get auto converted to QML, but just because `QList<int>` works and `QPoint` work, it is not necessary mean that `QList<QPoint>` will also work.

This is the list of automatic types in a list that QML supports:

```
QList<int>
QList<qreal>
QList<bool>
QList<QString> and QStringList
QList<QUrl>
QVector<int>
QVector<qreal>
QVector<bool>
```

As you see, `QPoint` is not one of them.

Wrapping in a `QObject` would be a waste.

But do not despair. I suggest you declare `QList<QPoint> *` as a meta type, then you can wrap that in a `QVariant` to pass it as a opaque pointer to QML. Then, in your `PlaneGridQML` or another, single `QObject` derived type, you implement an interface to get the size of the list and individual points at a given index.

You basically implement a standalone accessor / manipulator for lists of points. And you are all set.

I also [**strongly recommend**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33609406/qlist-vs-qvector-revisited/33946483#33946483) that you use `QVector` instead of `QList` in this scenario.

```
class PlaneGridQML : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ........
    Q_INVOKABLE QPoint get(int i) { return planesPoints[i]; }
    ...
}
...
console.log(PlaneGrid.get(0).x)
```

If you only have one plane grid and one set of points, you don't even need to pass the opaque pointer to QML, you can just directly use the plane grid to get the size and individual elements via index. Easy peasy.

Comment: I think QList<QVariant> (QVariantList) should work as well - just for completeness of your list... But I might err on this.

Comment: QVariantList works, but you will have to convert all the points to variants... doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: @dtech please allow me a few days to verify your suggestions.

Comment: @dtech when using the opaque pointer method how would I read the data in the JS code ?

Comment: @Cristi you'd have to pass it back to C++, convert it back to its actual type and simply use it to fetch the data. So it will be something like this in QML `Accessor.get(listVar, index)` and in C++ you will have like a `listVar.value<QList<QPoint>*>()->at(index)`. But again, **do not use `QList`** :)

Answer (score 0):

You can expose `QPoint` to QML, but not `QList<QPoint>`.
I see three possible solutions to your problem:

1. Add arguments to `PlaneGridQML::planesPointsChanged` signal. You cannot expose `QList<QPoint>` but you can send two variables of type `QList<qreal>` as the signal arguments. One list could hold `x` values and another `y` values.
2. Implement `int PlaneGridQML::getPlanesPointsCount()` and `QPoint PlaneGridQML::getPlanesPoint(int index)`. So you have two functions - one which returns how many points there are, and second which return point for each index.
3. Create a new class that will hold two variables (`planePointX`, `planePointY`) and return `QQmlListProperty<NewClass>` with `PlaneGridQML::getPlanesPoints`. However this approach is rather not a very good idea for your case (too complicated). [More info](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html#properties-with-object-list-types).